# Can I safely drop "http://" and "www" from URLs in QR codes?

Tags: http, url, qr-code, no-www

I would like to encode some links for QR codes.

The shorter the link the better, because a shorter URL reduces the number of dots in the QR code, which makes it a lot easier to scan.

If I remove "http://www." from the start of my URLs (qoomerang.com/xxxx), the link works fine on my computer. But are standards these days such that I can safely remove them from the QR code aswell - i.e. will the text still be recognised as a website by all smartphones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`www` is just a subdomain. Whether it's safe to drop this or not depends on the web server configuration. If the server is configured to serve a certain page on the `www` subdomain, it will need this.
(Refer to: https://superuser.com/questions/60006/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-www-subdomain for more details)

`http://` refers to the protocol and should be retained as this is the only reliable way of identifying a web address and the method to fetch it. Some devices try to find URLs that do not contain `http://` but you should not rely on this. Furthermore, the device would not know for certain whether it should use HTTP or HTTP over TLS (`https://`) to download the link.